# How to make an int return to his original value after modifying?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an RPG game for school purpose and I was wondering how can I take back the original value of an integer after modifying.

In my code, I have a fighter who can do a critical strike which will double his attack just for one turn, the problem is he keeps his attack amount for the rest of the game... Anybody have an idea ?

```
 func warriorAbility(_ attacker: Character, _ target: Character){

    attacker.weapon.damages *= 2

    print("\(attacker.name) the \(attacker.classe) use 'Battlecry !' and do a critical strike of \(attacker.weapon.damages) damages point. He double his atk !")
}
class Sword: Weapon{
init(){
    super.init(damages: 10, name: "Sword")
}
} class Fighter : Character{
init(name: String, classe: Classe){
    super.init(name: name, healthpoint: 100, maxHealthpoint: 100, weapon: Sword(), classe: classe)
}
```

}

edit : added my fighter class and sword class

Comment: you can store the default values or original values at another place and swap it whenever you need them.

Comment: What about using a `let defaultDamageValue = initialValue`, and reset afterwards `attacker.weapon.damages = defaultDamageValue`?

Comment: You haven't really shown enough code, but probably your `Character` or possibly your `Weapon` should have a `criticalMultiplier` property (which would be 2 in this case). Then when you compute the turn you would have an `isCritical` Boolean that lets you determine whether to use the critical multiplier or not; the `isCritical` is a modifier of the attack. You shouldn't change the actual stats of the player/weapon.

Comment: @Paulw11 I like your idea, but resetting the multiplier to 1 should be enough and wouldn't need to use the boolean, no?

Comment: Here the class of my weapon : import Foundation
class Sword: Weapon{
    init(){
        super.init(damages: 10, name: "Sword")
    }
}

Comment: The critical multiplier is a property of the weapon. Whether a particular attack is a critical attack or not is a property of the attack (hence the Boolean). All weapons would have a critical multiplier property, the default value of which would probably be 1 (I.e. a critical attack has no additional effect). Generally you don't want the stats of a player or object to change and then change back after the move; you have to store the old value and you might introduce a bug where it doesn't get restored.

Comment: @Bou you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53480231/edit) your question to include additional code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than changing the attribute of the weapon and then having to restore it, I would suggest you build critical damage into your game.

Something like:

```
struct Weapon {
   let damage: Int
   let criticalMultiplier: Int
   let name: String
}

let sword = Weapon(damage: 10, criticalMultiplier:2, name:"sword")

struct Move {
   let attacker: Character
   let target: Character
   let isCritical: Bool

   func damage() -> Int {
      return attacker.weapon.damage * isCritical ? attacker.weapon.criticalMultiplier : 1
   }
}
```